# Prove if $B^2=I+BA$ and $A^2=AB$ then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I need to prove that if $B^2=I+BA$ and $A^2=AB$ then $A=0$, $A$ and $B$ are square matrices. I'm not sure if my answer is correct but I thought of this:

$$
A^2-B^2=A^2+AB-BA-B^2=A^2+A^2-(B^2-I)-B^2=2(A^2-B^2)+I 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow B^2-A^2=I=(B-A)(B+A)
$$

This means that $(B-A)$ is invertible. It is also given that $I=B^2-AB$ then:
$$
B^2-AB=B^2-A^2
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow B(B-A)=(B+A)(B-A)
$$

Because we proved that $(B-A)$ is invertible then we can simplify and get $B=B+A \Rightarrow A=0$

Comment: How do you get $A^2-B^2=A^2+AB-BA-B^2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$

Comment: You do realise that $AB\ne BA$ in general?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you're right...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is $AB=BA$ in this case?

Comment: In this case $AB=BA$ since $A=0$. But can **you** prove that without solving the problem completely?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I obviously can't. It was just interesting to me that my solution worked out with that assumption, wondering if I could've changed in my solution to really make it work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$B^2 = I +BA\implies B(B - A) = I$, so $B-A$ is invertible; hence $A-B$ is invertible. Now:

$A^2 = AB \implies A(A-B) = 0 \implies A(A-B)(A-B)^{-1} = 0 \implies A = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

$A^3=ABA=A(B^2-I)=AB^2-A=(AB)B-A=A^2B-A=A(AB)-A=A^3-A$

$\implies A=0$